# preload javascript (ckeEditor.js wysiwyg) in another page before called

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to pre-load ckEditor [ckEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) before we even open the page in which the ckEditor.js javascript is being called?
I would like to do this as the ckEditor.js is a heavy 350kb file which for some user takes 20-30 sec to upload over the dialup connections. I wanna load it when the user has only opened the front page ( which is just a simple still html) and is busy reading the front page. and by the time he/she moves to the page where ckeditor is used, the ckeditor.js is already loaded and cached.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this by including CKEditor as a js file regularly on your home page, which will cause it to load into the cache before moving on to another page. The problem is that CKEdtior is usally linked to with some arbitrary number as a query string at the end of the file name which makes it uncacheable (ckeditor.js?v=12424324234 or something similar). You'll probably need to get into the CKEditor source (which I remember is a complete nightmare) and do a global find for where that file calls the JS file you're trying to cache, and make sure it doesn't include that variable query string on the end.